# Landmark updates in robot_localization

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently obtaining landmark updates for odometry which are not continuous position data and provide with discrete jumps in the position data. The '`robot_localization`' documentation mentions that the '`navsat_transform_node`'  essentially takes in the GPS data and converts it to an odometry message in the 'world frame'.

I have the two following questions with respect to this:

1. What is the `'world frame`' for the
   output odometry in this node?
2. Will
   the landmark updates for state
   estimation required to be with
   respect to the `odom frame` or
   `map frame`? (because they are
   discrete position updates)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207031/landmark-updates-in-robot_localization/) by [Sowmya](https://answers.ros.org/users/22132/sowmya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, see my answer to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/203989/map-frame-from-robot_localization/) question, which I think is similar to yours.

Second, are you taking in landmark updates to provide a (potentially discontinuous) pose estimate, or are you using GPS? `navsat_transform_node` is only necessary if you are working with GPS data.

A typical use case would be:

1. `ekf_localization_node` or `ukf_localization_node` instance one: fuse continuous measurement source, e.g., odometry and IMU data. The `world_frame` for this instance is the same value as your `odom_frame`; this is typically *odom*. **Alternatively**, some robots provide an odometry message and the *odom*->*base_link* transform. This is typically less accurate than a solution with fused data sources, but it may fit you needs.
2. `ekf_localization_node` or `ukf_localization_node` instance two: fuse the same data as in instance one, but also fuse discontinuous sources like GPS or position updates from landmark observations. The `world_frame` for this instance is the same value as your `map_frame`; this is typically *map*. This instance is really only necessary if you have discontinuous measurement sources.

To more directly answer your question, for `navsat_transform_node`, the `frame_id` of the `/odometry/gps` message that gets created is depedent on the frame_id of the odometry message that gets fed to it.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1